# AOP Unity and EF POCO best workflow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, enterprise-library

I want to “inject” AOP aspects on a domain POCO class using a Unity container at the moment when the POCO object is being constructed from the database by Entity Framework ORM

Unity can easily “inject” AOP aspects  on an POCO class using two ways (let’s analyze the pros and cons)

1)  Interface Interceptor

you get a proxy OBJECT that IS NOT A DERIVED object of your POCO class.

YOU CAN ADD  APO TO A PREVIOUSLY EXISTING POCO object, you DON’T  NEED TO INSTANCIATE A NEW ONE.

or

2)  VirtualMethod Interceptor

you get an object THAT IS A DERIVED object of your POCO class.

you CAN’T ADD AOP TO A PREVIOUSLY EXISTING POCO object, you  NEED TO INSTANCIATE A NEW ONE.

Furthermore.. we can.

a) CONFIGURE THE Unity CONTAINER and use the Resolve method.

or

b)MANUALY DO THE AOP injection by the Intercept class WITHOUT having to configure a Unity CONTAINER.

I could also retrieve the POCO objects from the database through EF and then use the Intercept class with an Interface Interceptor just for injecting AOP over the previously retrieved objects. But the result won’t be derived object of the POCO class.

So what I would need on some EF point (event) is to tell to EF that it must use the Unity container to resolve the POCO class (or use the Intercept class with an VirtualMethod Interceptor), thus the AOP will be injected and the object will be derived of the POCO class.

BR Alex

Answer (score 0):

I am considering using PostSharp for such interceptions

But If I was forced to use Unity to do it, the only approach that I can imagine is to use a Interface for resolution and a Decorator pattern.

The drawback is that the implementation will be tedious a less easy to maintain on long run.

Worth to mention that you SHOULD NEVER access properties not declared on the interface NOR pointed by the decorator, since changes to those properties won't be reflected

However as an exercise here below the code that could be implemented

```
public interface IProduct
{
    int ProductID { get; set; }
    string ProductName { get; set; }
    decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IProduct
{
    public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int? SupplierID { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public short? UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
    public short? ReorderLevel { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
}

public class AopProduct : Product
{
    private readonly IProduct _product;

    public override int ProductID { get { return _product.ProductID; } set { _product.ProductID = value; } }
    public override string ProductName { get { return _product.ProductName; } set { _product.ProductName = value; } }
    public override decimal? UnitPrice { get { return _product.UnitPrice; } set { _product.UnitPrice = value; } }

    public AopProduct(IProduct product)
    {
        _product = Intercept.ThroughProxy(product, new InterfaceInterceptor(), new IInterceptionBehavior[] { new LoggingInterceptionBehavior() });
    }
}

public class LoggingInterceptionBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking {0} at {1}", input.MethodBase.Name, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public bool WillExecute => true;
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AopProductShouldHaveAspectsAndBeProduct()
    {
        var product = new Product();

        var aopProduct = new AopProduct(product) { ProductID = 100, ProductName = "a product", UnitPrice = 12.5m };

        DisplayProduct(aopProduct);

        Assert.IsTrue(aopProduct is Product);
    }

    private static void DisplayProduct(Product product)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{product.ProductID} - {product.ProductName} - {product.UnitPrice}");
    }
}
```

If we run the code shows

Invoking set_ProductID at 0:53:36

Invoking set_ProductID at 0:53:36

Invoking set_ProductName at 0:53:36

Invoking set_ProductName at 0:53:36

Invoking set_UnitPrice at 0:53:36

Invoking set_UnitPrice at 0:53:36

Invoking get_ProductID at 0:53:36

Invoking get_ProductID at 0:53:36

Invoking get_ProductName at 0:53:36

Invoking get_ProductName at 0:53:36

Invoking get_UnitPrice at 0:53:36

Invoking get_UnitPrice at 0:53:36

100 - a product - 12,5

Answer (score 0):

Now compare the PostSharp solution, you don't need nothing extra, no interface, no decorator, no Unity, just your plain POCO class.
I had only "marked" as virtual some properties just to distinguish them from the ones that I don't want to attach aspects, but is up to you to decide how apply the aspects.

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int? SupplierID { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public short? UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
    public short? ReorderLevel { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public sealed class LoggingOnMethodBoundaryAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking {0} at {1}", args.Method.Name, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{


    [TestMethod]
    public void PSharpAopProductShouldHaveAspectsAndBeProduct()
    {
        var product = new Product() { ProductID = 100, ProductName = "a product", UnitPrice = 12.5m };

        DisplayProduct(product);
    }

    private static void DisplayProduct(Product product)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{product.ProductID} - {product.ProductName} - {product.UnitPrice}");
    }

}
```

and the GlobalAspects.cs file content

```
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

[assembly: LoggingOnMethodBoundaryAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "EFUnityAOPTest.Product", AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Virtual)]
```

If we run the code shows

Invoking set_ProductID at 1:10:39

Invoking set_ProductName at 1:10:39

Invoking set_UnitPrice at 1:10:39

Invoking get_ProductID at 1:10:39

Invoking get_ProductName at 1:10:39

Invoking get_UnitPrice at 1:10:39

100 - a product - 12,5

Happy coding

BR Alex